Inserting a text box with white background inside an eps figure
In the eps figure below, I'd like to replace -4 with $-4$ and 4 with $4$ (actually there is the need to replace all the tick labels).

Unfortunately, this does not work:
\begin{figure}
\centering
\psfrag{-4}[cc][Bc]{$-4$}
\includegraphics[]{Tc.eps}
        \end{figure}

because it seems that \psfrag cannot recognize -4 as a tag.
This other
\begin{figure}
\centering
\psfrag{4}[cc][Bc]{$-4$}
\includegraphics[]{Tc.eps}
        \end{figure}

substitutes all the 4 (but the minus in -4 is still visible), resulting in

What is the best way to solve the problem?
In alternative, we could insert a text box with a white backgroung to cover the -4 in the eps figure in the \begin{figure} environment with \includegraphics. But I don't know how to do this. I tries
\begin{figure}
\begin{picture}(0,0)\put(-3.2cm,-5.6cm){\colorbox{white}{$-4$}}\end{picture}
\includegraphics[]{Tc.eps}
\end{figure}

but is does not seem to work either, since it results in a transparent background.

Thanks in advance.
Update: I added the .eps as required, dropbox file and pastebin file1.

Sorry to say, the details you provided was not clear, please explain the issue with some clear picture like screenshot or image, etc.

The order of the commands is wrong. You must add your picture with the box after the \includegraphics so that it can overwrite the graphic. (And without the eps it is impossible to say what it uses internally for the minus).

The link to the EPS leads to a page that asks me to register with Dropbox. If the file is not too big you can add the source as an edit to your question here (an EPS file is plain text, you can open it in a text editor), or maybe use Pastebin if the EPS source code is very large.

@UlrikeFischer, it works, thanks!!

your pastebin files errors but you could try to replace the minus independently with \psfrag{-}[cc][Bc]{$-$}

@UlrikeFischer, this is an other possibility, thanks!

This example uses example.eps included with the package psfrag documentation.
The colored numbers on the axes show the changes made to the original figure.

% !TeX TS-program = pdflatex
    
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}   % modern font encoding
\usepackage{auto-pst-pdf} % Wrapper for pst-pdf (with some psfrag features)
\usepackage{psfrag} %Replace strings in encapsulated PostScript figures

\begin{document}

Using example.eps included with the package \textsf{psfrag} documentation.

\bigskip

\begin{figure}[tbh]
    \unitlength=1in
    \begin{center}
            \psfragscanon % to notify PSfrag that it must scan example.eps  for the \tex tags.
            \psfrag{2}[][][0.8]{\color{red}$\mathsf{2}$} 
            \psfrag{4}[][][0.8]{\color{red}$\mathsf{4}$}
            \psfrag{8}[][][0.8]{\color{red}$\mathsf{8}$}
            \psfrag{10}[][][0.8]{\color{red}$\mathsf{10}$}
            \psfrag{-0.8}[r][r][0.8]{\color{green}$\mathsf{-0.8}$} 
            \psfrag{0.8}[r][r][0.8]{\color{green}$\mathsf{0.8}$}                
            \psfrag{-1}[r][r][0.8]{\color{green}$\mathsf{-1}$}
            \includegraphics[width=3.5in]{example.eps}
    \end{center}
    \caption{A \textsf{psfrag} example.}
\end{figure}

\end{document}

To get correct typeset psfrag  stuff when compiling tex-->pdf directly, you should use the package auto-pst-pdf, which in a first run creates a file \jobname-pics.pdf, which collects all eps files converted to pdf embedding pstricks stuff.
\psfrag{tag}[posn][psposn][scale][rot]{replacement}
The optional positioning arguments [posn] and [psposn] specify how the bounding box of the LATEX
text and the bounding box of the PostScript text line up.
To turn on scanning for a single figure, precede the  \includegraphics
command with a call to the command \psfragscanon. Scanning will be turned off again
when the surrounding environment is exited.
See http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/psfrag/pfgguide.pdf

If I understand the question then the issue is that the negative tick labels like -4 in OP's figure are not represented as a unit in the EPS, which happens frequently in exported figures from various tools (i.e., the - and the 4 are represented as separate PostScript drawing commands, and psfrag doesn't see them as a unit that can be replaced). Therefore I think your answer is not really applicable to the current question. Also the \psfragscanon command is only used to run \tex commands embedded in the EPS, which the OP presumably doesn't have.

An alternative solution could be to add \tex commands in the figure (if the tool that produced the EPS allows for that) and then not use \psfrag replacements but instead only use \psfragscanon to render the commands.

However, the OP asked about their own alternative solution, which is to overlay the graphic with manually positioned tick marks from within LaTeX (without using psfrag at all). While maybe not the most elegant or scalable solution it could work in principle.

@Marijn The question does not include the .eps figure. It's hard to guess what command it might contains.

We don't have the EPS but we can still say some things. It does not contain \tex commands, because otherwise they would be visible in the second screenshot of the OP as raw code strings, because this screenshot was made using just \includegraphics without psfrag. Moreover, the OP knows how to use psfrag properly because in the first screenshot the 4 from the EPS is replaced by a 4 from LaTeX. It just doesn't work for -4 because this is represented differently in the EPS of the OP. How exactly we don't know, but it is such that psfrag replacements don't work unless you edit the EPS.

@SimonDispa, unfortunately it does not work. Below my code:
\begin{figure} \begin{center} \psfragscanon \psfrag{-4}[r][r][0.8]{$-4$} \includegraphics[]{figures/Tc.eps} \end{center} \end{figure}

@umby Could you share Tc.eps?

@SimonDispa, I tried to upload it, see the update at the bootm of my question. Thanks.
